# bdist_mac cx_freeze with Tkinter and Selenium interaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I created a Python 3 application that has a Tkinter GUI and a Selenium action upon clicking a button. I'm compiling it via cx_freeze. Here is the `setup.py` file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path    

buildOptions = {"include_files":['execute.py'], "packages": ['encodings'], "includes": ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format'], "excludes": []}

if sys.platform=='win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"
else:
    base=None

executables = [
    Executable('bot_gui.py', base=base)
]

home_path = str(Path.home())

user_txt_path = []

if sys.platform=='win32':
    print("windows detected")
    user_txt_path.append('\\user.txt')
else:
    print("macos detected")
    user_txt_path.append('/user.txt')

#for initialization
f = open(home_path + user_txt_path[0], "w+")
for i in range(12):
     f.write("---\n")

setup(name='tachysloth',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'test',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

When I run `python setup.py build` everything works fine; but when I run `python setup.py bdist_mac`, the GUI works when you click on the application (called tachysloth-1.0 below).

[image: Screenshot of running application]

Whe I click on a button to in the GUI to open `google.com` in Chrome, the button does not do anything.

If you need more information to assess this problem, please let me know and I will provide that information as soon as possible.

Comment: do you get any error message when you run `exe` in console/terminal ? Put this message (Traceback) in questiona (as text , not screenshot).

Comment: @furas like not when i double click on the application but when i open it via the terminal?

Comment: run `exe` in terminal manually - it may shows you error messages with useful informations.

Comment: you can also add many `print()` with informations in code before compiling and after compiling you can see those informations in terminal and you will see when/where it stops/freezes and which part of code doesn't run correctly. It's called "print debuging"

Comment: @furas ok will do right now

Comment: @furas no errors occured when i use the `open` command with the directory to my exe. also i want to specify that i am on macos.

Comment: I use Linux and I can open terminal and run it without `open` (I may have to only set "executable" attribute `chmod +x exe_file`). Can you do the same - without `open` ?

Comment: @furas well the application is a .app application so does it work the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162756/discussion-between-julian-rachman-and-furas).

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question, but you're including a python file as a file instead of a library, is there any reason for this? and could that be the reason? if you're executing the file instead of importing it that may explain why it fails to run? and if it needs to be executed then maybe it also needs to be converted?

Comment: @JamesKent I do not see any reason. Could you elaborate?

Comment: ok so cx_Freeze packages your main script into an executable, but i have yet to find a way to make that executable run anything other than the frozen script, so if for example you are doing something like `subprocess.call('execute.py')` i don't think it would work, but if you're doing `import execute` then it should still work, but then i have no idea why you aren't just adding it to your library includes...

Comment: if you are trying to call it then i'd suggest you need to freeze that script too and adjust the main script to be able to call either the `.py` or the frozen script depending on whether the main script is frozen or not

Comment: @JamesKent I am importing a class from `execute.py`. Should I just combine the two files into one then create the executable out of that?

Comment: just try removing it from include_files and add it as `includes=[... "execute"]`

Comment: @JamesKent it comes up with an error saying execute does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163310/discussion-between-james-kent-and-julian-rachman).